# Variables globales en symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Necesito crear un listado de constantes globales en symfony. Estas variables se van a usar en la gran mayoría de los controladores.
Había pensado hacer una clase con las constantes y después hacer un 'use' en aquellos controladores donde se van a usar. ¿Es esta una buena idea? Cuál es la mejor opción para crear estas variables. Estoy trabajando con symfony4.

Mi idea sería hacer algo así

```
 
namespace App\VariablesGlobales;
 
class MisVariables
{
    const MATERIAL = 'Madera';
    const BORDE= 3;
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo no las pondría en una clase global, utilizaría la configuración o las variables de entorno (env):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables

Comment: Yo lo veo más a variables de entorno. Las agrupas para ordenarlas y luego en tus controladores inyectado un interface ParameterBagInterface para utilizar el servicio de parámetros.

Comment: Yo avogo por ponerlas en la configuracion, las variables de entorno lo dice su nombre: entorno, se prestan más para almacenar configuraciones referentes a la infraestructura de despliegue (DSN de base de datos, servidores de cache, colas de mensaje, etc); tampoco significa que no sea una opción para lo que el usuario desea en este caso